# BLE Characteristic notifications not working every time

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a Qt Android app that that needs to communicate with a Raspberry Pi through Bluetooth Low Energy in order to exchange a series of configuration values required for starting an Ultra Wideband ranging session. I came to the realization that the data exchange gets blocked sometimes, when I run the Raspberry Pi server program, due to the notifications for a characteristic involved in the data exchanged not being enabled and thus, the phone is not aware that the data on that characteristic has changed, and won't respond back. In order to enable notifications on the Raspberry Pi, the Qt app runs the following code:

```
void DeviceHandlerBase::onServiceStateChangedUwb(QLowEnergyService::ServiceState s)
{
    if (s == QLowEnergyService::RemoteServiceDiscovered)
    {
        if (m_service == nullptr)
        {
            LOGE("UWB SERVICE POINTER IS NULL");
            return;
        }

        // To be moved to CONFIG.H
        txCharacteristic = m_service->characteristic(UWB::UWB_TX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
        rxCharacteristic = m_service->characteristic(UWB::UWB_RX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);

        if (txCharacteristic.isValid() && rxCharacteristic.isValid())
        {
            LOGI("The RX and TX Characteristics were found and are valid");
            m_notificationDesc = txCharacteristic.descriptor(UWB::UWB_DESCRIPTOR_UUID);

            if (m_notificationDesc.isValid())
            {
                LOGI("The notification descriptor is valid");
                LOGI("Desc UUID: " + m_notificationDesc.uuid().toString());
                LOGI((m_notificationDesc.type()));

                // Reset the value of the notification descriptor ?!
                // This might interfere with onConfirmedDescriptorWriteUwb
                // m_service->writeDescriptor(m_notificationDesc, UWB::BLE_DISABLE_NOTIFICATIONS);


                m_service->writeDescriptor(m_notificationDesc, UWB::BLE_ENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS);
            }
            else
                LOGE("THE NOTIFICATION DESCRIPTOR IS NOT VALID");
        }
        else
            LOGE("THE RX AND TX CHARACTERISTICS ARE NOT VALID");
    }
}
```

This writes the 0x0100 to the CCCD descriptor, and should enable notifications from the RPi.
For the RPi server, I use the DBUS Bluez API for BLE interactions, and hence I have tried to monitor the Bluez DBUS messages for debugging purposes.

As I have mentioned, the exchange either works or not randomly, when running the server program, and
I have spotted the following differences in the DBUS messages:

When the notifications are working fine:

```
Type=method_call  Endian=l  Flags=1  Version=1 Cookie=2651
  Sender=:1.16  Destination=:1.99  Path=/org/bluez/dbz_application/service_0/char_1  Interface=org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1  Member=StartNotify
  UniqueName=:1.16
  MESSAGE "" {
  };
```

When the notifications are not working:

```
Type=method_call  Endian=l  Flags=0  Version=1 Cookie=2844
  Sender=:1.16  Destination=:1.107  Path=/org/bluez/dbz_application/service_0/char_1/desc_0  Interface=org.bluez.GattDescriptor1  Member=WriteValue
  UniqueName=:1.16
  MESSAGE "aya{sv}" {
          ARRAY "y" {
                  BYTE 1;
                  BYTE 0;
          };
          ARRAY "{sv}" {
                  DICT_ENTRY "sv" {
                          STRING "device";
                          VARIANT "o" {
                                  OBJECT_PATH "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_B0_0A_B8_27_BF";
                          };
                  };
                  DICT_ENTRY "sv" {
                          STRING "link";
                          VARIANT "s" {
                                  STRING "LE";
                          };
                  };
                  DICT_ENTRY "sv" {
                          STRING "mtu";
                          VARIANT "q" {
                                  UINT16 517;
                          };
                  };
          };
  };
```

Are you aware of any reason for which the WriteValue method gets called for the descriptor instead of the StartNotify method for the characteristic that owns the notification descriptor ?